# Fread reads double from a file

Tags: c, compare, fread, strcmp

I am new to C programming and I am trying to compare blocks of 1024 bytes (I'm testing with 10 for now) from 2 txt files, and check how many of those blocks are identical.

I am reading blocks with fread and comparing them with strcmp, but fread reads double from the first file, even if I read in the same way from both. So this is my compare function:

```
void compareFiles(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2)
{
char fp1_content[10]; //should be 1024
char fp2_content[10]; //should be 1024

fread(fp1_content, 10, 1, fp1); //should be 1024
fread(fp2_content, 10, 1, fp2); //should be 1024

printf("content of 81.txt %s \n", fp1_content);
printf("content of 82.txt %s \n", fp2_content);

char ch1 = getc(fp1);
char ch2 = getc(fp2);
int eqBlocks = 0;

while (ch1 != EOF && ch2 != EOF)
{
    if (strcmp(fp1_content, fp2_content) == 0) {
        eqBlocks++;
    }

    ch1 = getc(fp1);
    ch2 = getc(fp2);

    fread(fp1_content, 10, 1, fp1);
    fread(fp2_content, 10, 1, fp2);
}
printf("Nb of identical blocks: %d\n", eqBlocks);
}
```

Here comes the issue: I have lorem ipsum text, same text in both files. But the first two printfs are outputing:

```
content of 81.txt Lorem ipsuLorem ipsu
content of 82.txt Lorem ipsu
```

Why is the first one doubled? How am I fixing this?

Comment: Why are you using `fread` with text files?

Comment: OP is trying to compare files by blocks "

I am trying to compare blocks of 1024 bytes"

Comment: btw you lose 1 character each time with your getc call. Better check return value from fread...

Comment: .. and `strcmp`? How does a block read magically terminate strings?

Comment: that is a good point. memcmp is better

Comment: You're not null-terminating your buffers before trying to print them with `printf` using `%s`.  So a lot of what you're seeing is stray garbage.  Everything after the first 10 characters of the first buffer is coming from the second buffer.  Add `'\0` to the end of both buffers (allow an extra byte for it) and the doubling problem will disappear.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Nah, OP just forgot to null-terminate the buffers, so the first printf is going right through the first buffer and into the second.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, the other file doesn't have a newline, that's why this is wierd. At least for me, I'm new to C, and I am printing the result of fread before getc call. Or am I missing something?

Comment: oh, good. @TomKarzes, how am I null-terminating the buffers then? :D

Comment: After the data, append a `'\0'` character to each buffer.  If you read 10 characters, then it needs to be the 11th, i.e. `buffer[10] = '\0';` So you need to allocate an additional character for it, e.g. `char buffer[11]`.  But if you read less than 10 characters, then you should terminate it sooner.  The return value from `fread` will tell you how many items were read.

Comment: cool. I'll try that, thanks so much @TomKarzes for pointing it out and for the explanation!

Comment: Look, you have a loop `while (ch1 != EOF && ch2 != EOF)` which is reading one byte at a time. You try to superimpose `fread` on top of that and compare with `strcmp`. Forget all that `fread` and `strcmp` **nonsense**: just compare `if(ch1 != ch2) { ... }`. Note too, it should be `int ch1, ch2`.

Comment: also thanks Jean-François Fabre and Weather Vane for the suggestions!

Comment: `char ch1 = getc(fp1);` is wrong with a binary file. Should be `int ch1 = getc(fp1);`. If 255 is in the binary file you may get a wrong EOF. Anyway, just use returncode from fgets.

Comment: ...also you say you want to compare blocks of 1024 bytes, so alternatively drop the `getc` and just use `fread` and then compare them with `memcmp`. The *number of bytes* compared must be the **return value** from the two `freads` which must be the same. If the objective is to compare two files for equality, forget about using any string functions.

Comment: the thing with getc was that I wanted to take the rest of contents left after I take first 10 bytes, and just wanted to know when the file is at the end. didn't know how to do that without. what's a better/an option of taking another 10 bytes from the file after the first have been checked?

Comment: You know the file is at an end when `fread` returns `0` (the `count` of ***items*** of `size` which were read). I recommend `itemsread = fread(fp1_content, 1, 1024, fp1);` not `itemsread = fread(fp1_content, 1024, 1, fp1);`. Can you see the difference? Function `fread` returns the number of items of the specified size which were read. It only returns the number of bytes, if the `size` given was `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's code needs a few fixes.

**Return value**

Functions like `fread()` return useful info.  Use them.  It this case, it tells how much was read. [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56316902/fread-reads-double-from-a-file/56318100#comment99243403_56316902)

**"%s" expectes a *string* pointer**

`printf("content of 81.txt %s \n", fp1_content);` expects `fp1_content` is a *string*.  In C, a *string* always has a *null character*, else, it is not a string.  To print text that may not have a `'\0'`, use `"%.*s"`, which accepts an argument to limit print length.  `"%s"` with a non-string is *undefined behavior*.  Unexpected things may happen. [@Tom Karzes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56316902/fread-reads-double-from-a-file/56318100#comment99243010_56316902)

**Compare non-strings with `memcmp()`**

**Unnecessary code**

`char ch1 = getc(fp1);` is not need to detect the end, use the `fread()` return value.  [@Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56316902/fread-reads-double-from-a-file/56318100#comment99242954_56316902) Aside: use `int ch1` to distinguish the 257 different return values from `fgets()`.

**Avoid naked magic numbers**

Rather than litter code with `10` here and there, use a named constant.

**Think big**

Files can be larger than `INT_MAX` blocks.  Suggest `long long eqBlocks`.

```
#include <limits.h>
#define COMPAREFILES_N 10
#if COMPAREFILES_N > INT_MAX
#error Use smaller block
#endif

void compareFiles(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2) {
  char fp1_content[COMPAREFILES_N];
  char fp2_content[COMPAREFILES_N];
  long long eqBlocks = 0;

  for (;;) {
    size_t len1 = fread(fp1_content, COMPAREFILES_N, 1, fp1);
    size_t len2 = fread(fp2_content, COMPAREFILES_N, 1, fp2);
    if (len1 < 1 || len2 < 1) {
      break;  // failed to read a block in each file
    }
    if (memcmp(fp1_content, fp2_content, COMPAREFILES_N) == 0) {
      eqBlocks++;
      printf("Common content `%.*s`\n", COMPAREFILES_N, fp1_content);
    }
  }

  printf("Nb of identical blocks: %lld\n", eqBlocks);
}
```